# Typing issue when pulling strings from clip board

Tags: java, database, redis

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    String result;
    try {
        result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        console.appendText("\nString being registerd to account: " + result);

        Jedis client = new Jedis("placeholder");
        client.rpush(userName, result);
        client.disconnect();
        client.close();
```

When i run the code from a button, i get an error saying that result is the wrong data type. Does it have to do with how i pull text from the clipboard and is there another way to do this so it doesn't throw this error?
stack:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:222)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.rpush(Jedis.java:813)
at Commands.NEW.excecute(NEW.java:25)
at Controllers.mainController.parseCommand(mainController.java:100)
at Controllers.mainController.submitHandler(mainController.java:57)
... 58 more
```

Comment: The error is on the `client.rpush`  - whatever that is.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I need to know why its doing that when- i assume- i am pushing a String. Or another way i can do it.

Comment: without seeing the relevant parts of the `jedis` code, we would only be guessing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was trying to push it without selecting the right database.